# Expand a CSS Div only if content stretches it

Tags: css

I am working on a new blog site, it will document my code and such.  I have a syntax highlighter which looks like the image below...

---

[image]

---

I have this CSS

```
.syntaxhighlighter {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 1em 0 1em 0 !important;
  position: relative !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
  font-size: .9em !important;
}

.syntaxhighlighter:hover {
  width: 135% !important;
}
```

As you can see in the image, the syntax highlited code is a certain width to fit in my layout, I am experimenting with making it wider when hovered for when the there is code that makes it wider then my content div.

That is where I added the `.syntaxhighlighter:hover` class and it works, when I hover the sytax highlighter div, it expands to the width I set.  Now the only thing I am hoping to change if it's even possible....

I would like to somehow only expand the highlighter div width IF the code inside it stretches beyond the normal width.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can try is to set `min-width: 100%;` and then set `display:inline-block;`  This will mean that the width is determined by the content (having preformatted content means that it won't wrap either), but it won't shrink inappropriately because of the minimum width.  You may find it desirable to set a `max-width` as well.

Aside: be careful of over-using the `!important` directive - usually it isn't necessary if you are specific with your selectors, and sometimes it messes up accessibility (e.g. if someone requires an overriding stylesheet to view webpages).

Comment: Thank you, I think this works, under my `.syntaxhighlighter` I set `max-width: 100%;` and ` display:inline-block;` and then for `.syntaxhighlighter:hover` I set `max-width: 135%;` So the div has a max width of 100%, except when hovered, max width increases so that when a certain div is under the hover max width, it shows no change, works good, just hope all browsers will support it, thanks again